# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).chosen is not a function in rails application

Tags: javascript, jquery-chosen

I am using chosen library in my rails application and running into "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).chosen is not a function" error.

I installed using npm :

```
"npm install chosen-js"
```

Code :

```
<div data-controller="dropdown">
<select id="abcMenu" class= "chosen-select" data-action="dropdown#abc">
    <option value="/abc">A</option>
    <option value="/xyz">B</option>
    <option value="/def">C</option>
</select>
</div>
```

/app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require turbolinks
//= require local-time
//= require moment
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".chosen-select").chosen()
});
```

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to copy the javascript file to your app/assets/javascripts directory then require it in application.js. I dont think npm does that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to apply `chosen` via `turbolinks:load` event:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $(".chosen-select").chosen();
});
```